# 見出し一覧を表示して、そこからジャンプする機能

Tags: emacs

emacs の標準で、現在のバッファに対して見出しの一覧を作成・表示し、その中から行きたい見出しを選択すると、そこへジャンプできるような機能があった記憶があるのですが、それが何なのか思い出せずにいます。

この機能は、何という名前の機能だったでしょうか。

`occur` のように検索をかけてその一覧を表示する機能ではなく、その buffer の major mode が定義する見出しのようなものを一覧に表示して、そこからジャンプする機能、です。

Comment: `occur` でしょうか？

Comment: @argus occur は、バッファに対して grep してその一覧を表示する機能、だったと記憶しています。そうではなくって、曖昧なんですが、「その major mode が定義する見出しっぽいものの一覧」を表示して、そこからジャンプできるような機能、です。

Comment: では `imenu` でしょうか。ただ、見出し一覧は menu bar の Index から選ぶか、`M-x imenu` として入力していく事になりますが…。

Comment: @argus あ、これです。 imenu が欲しかった名前でした。

Comment: @argus (ので、回答に記述いただけると、 accept が押せるのですが。。

Comment: Inoue さん自身で回答・承認で良いと思いますよ。できれば `imenu` の簡単な使い方(もしくは解説記事へのリンクなど)も添えて貰えると嬉しいかも。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`M-x imenu` が求めていたものでした。

参考までに、 `M-x imenu` 実行時の挙動の図

[image: imenu 実行画面]